# flume HDFS sink custom file name

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, flume

Is there any way to configure(dynamically through Event) file name in HDFS sink stored by flume ? HDFS sink provides following name configuration.

```
hdfs.filePrefix
hdfs.fileSuffix
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can configure the file name in HDFS sink by the following parameters.

```
hdfs.filePrefix = <<FILE_PREFIX>>-%{host}-%d-%H-%m-%s
hdfs.fileSuffix = <<FILE_SUFFIX>>-%{host}-%d-%H-%m-%s

%{host} = "It will pick up the hostname of your machine"
%t = "It will provide unix time in milliseconds "
%d= "Date"
%H= "Hour"
%m= "minutes"
%s= "seconds"
```

Thus Flume Bucket writer opens threads to hdfs to write, by using the "Prifix/Suffix" we can dynamically create filename.

Comment: Can you please describe?

Comment: Is there any way to define it programmatically? e.g. custom document id.I have already tried with Configurable interface but no success.